# three.js filmpass noise becomes weird after a while

Tags: three.js, post-processing

https://codepen.io/chrisjdesigner/pen/ExNPqBx

```
  // Old Film Look
  filmPass = new THREE.FilmPass();
  composer.addPass(filmPass);
```

In this example you can see it and it's something I've been having in my own tests as well. I'm not sure if it's only tabbing out or if by leaving the computer idle it eventually turns like that.

The way to replicate it is to open the demo, leave the tab for a while and after 15 minutes or so, when you return to the tab, the noise will look displaced and forming patterns
[image: such as this one]. Chrome latest version.

My assumption is that the requestanimationframe is causing this issue, but I wouldn't know what to tweak to fix it.

Anyone got a pointer?

Comment: You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"* ([Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers))

Answer (score -1):

It appears adding a deltatime to the render alleviates the issue greatly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).